# Anyone know if QAccelerometer works under Qt 5.3.2?

Tags: android, c++, qt

I am trying to use the accelerometer of the mobile, and it seems that it is recognized. It does not start() and is not able to read the info. 
The device does have accelerometer and the debugging options are on. 
The Qt application works on the device, showing the answer on a QLabel. The answer is that the sensor returns false when start() is called.

```
accel = new QAccelerometer(this);
bool bRet = accel->start();
```

I am working with Qt Creator 3.2.1 based on Qt 5.3.2, programming on C++. 
Thanks in advance,